# Not being able to store value from ReadLine (bufferedReader)

Tags: java, inputstream, bufferedreader

So I'm having issues with being able to save values using the method readLine() in bufferedReader, here is how my code is looking currently:

```
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
            while((inputLine=in.readLine())!= null)
                try { g.doc.insertString(g.doc.getLength(), "\n" + new Xmlgetter(inputLine).outString, g.style); 
                }
                catch (BadLocationException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

What I want to achieve is to be able to use the value of inputLine twice. The problem I'm running into is no matter how I try to save it I call on in.readLine(), which when called on a second time is empty. Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store the read value into a variable and reuse it any time you need it.

Use the usual pattern:

```
variable = readValue;
while (variable != null) {
    // use the variable value any times
    variable = readNextValue;
}
```